# Correct directory structure for Puppet RSpec testing

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I'm having some issues creating unit tests for my Puppet control repository.
I mostly work with roles and profiles with the following directory structure:

```
[root@puppet]# tree site
site
├── profile
│   ├── files
│   │   └── demo-website
│   │       └── index.html
│   └── manifests
│       ├── base.pp
│       ├── ci_runner.pp
│       ├── docker.pp
│       ├── gitlab.pp
│       ├── logrotate.pp
│       └── website.pp
├── role
│   └── manifests
│       ├── gitlab_server.pp
│       └── nginx_webserver.pp
```

Where do I need to place my spec files and what are the correct filenames?
I tried placing them here:

```
[root@puppet]# cat spec/classes/profile_ci_runner_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe 'profile::ci_runner' do
...
```

But I get an error:

Could not find class ::profile::ci_runner

Answer (score 0):

The conventional place for a module's spec tests is *in the module*, with the `spec/` directory in the module root.  So `site/profile/spec/classes/ci_runner_spec.rb`, for example.

You could consider installing [PDK](https://puppet.com/docs/pdk/1.x/pdk.html), which can help you set up the structure and run tests, among other things.